# laravel stuck with flash message

Tags: php, laravel

I have downloaded the auth ui package and I'm trying to overide the register function in the register controller:

```
public function postRegister(Request $request) {
    $response = parent::postRegister($request);

    $request->session()->flash('status', "Thanks, You've been registered and logged in."); 

    return $response;
}
```

And in the view:

```
@if(session('status'))
    <div class="msg success">
        {{session('status')}}
    </div>
@endif
```

This registers the user but does not display the flash message. Any suggestions?

I tried this one, which does display the flash message but doesn't register:

public function register(Request $request){

```
    Session::flash('success', 'test');
    return redirect()->route('home')' 
}
```

Comment: return back()->with('status', "Thanks, You've been registered and logged in.");

Comment: I tried this but it is the same. it registers but no message: public function postRegister(Request $request){
}
  $response = parent::postRegister($request);

        return back()->with('status', "Thanks, You've been registered and logged in.");
         return $response;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Hello your controller is ok.

To display your message in blade you need to do that :

```
@if(Session::has('status'))
{{ (Session::get('status')) }}
@endif
```

Comment: I tried this as well, but it doesn't display it either, something isn't right. Can you inspect flash messages with f12? @if(Session::has('status'))
      <div class="msg success">
    {{ (Session::get('status')) }}
    </div>
    @endif

Comment: When I get the flash message for regular log in, I see it of course with f12 view. When I register and check it is nothing there for some reason

Comment: Okay in your controller add :

return redirect(route('your route', ['response' => $response]));

in view : 
{{ request()->response}}

Hope this trick work :D

Comment: It returned nothing as well unfortunately

Comment: Add me on discord plz Vincent#2308

Comment: I just find this button to copy paste the server https://discord.gg/7PbynkYJ

Answer (score 0):

```
@if (Session::has('status'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-block">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
       <strong>{!! Session('status') !!}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: I tried that now, it didn't work either. Any debugging tips?